# Converting base64 string into image and send in email using laravel

Tags: laravel, vuejs2, tinymce

I am using tinymce-vue editor to get the users information and laravel to store it. This information can be either regular text or images. The problem that I am experiencing is that because tinymce stores images as base64 I am unable to send users input in an email as is.

For eg: If the user uploads an image inside tinymce, inserts additional content beneath the image and saves the information entered, this information is stored together inside a column, and then at an appointed time the information is sent out in an email. However, the email body displays the base64 string along with the other user information and html tags.

Is there a way to search the string for the base64 encoded data, retrieve it from the string, convert it into an image and replace the original base64 data with the actual image and send it via emal?

I attempted to perform the task but the image does not appear within the email body.I'm using laravel Notifications

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The major mistake I made was using Laravel's notification to send the information. Instead, I had to use [Laravel mailalbes](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/mail#generating-markdown-mailables) to solve the problem. It automatically dealt with the output of the images from Tinymce.

Answer (score 0):

What you are really asking here are two separate questions...

1. How do I take Base64 binary images from TinyMCE and store them in an appropriate format?
2. What is the best way to include images in an HTML email?

**How do I take Base64 binary images from TinyMCE and store them in an appropriate format**

TinyMCE has a built in mechanism to address this via its `images_upload_url` configuration option.  There is an entire page in the TinyMCE documentation on how this works:

https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/advanced/handle-async-image-uploads/

The net is that you can have TinyMCE send the image files to an endpoint of your choosing and then convert it to whatever format you need.  You don't need to keep it as a Base64 binary and it is very rare that you want the Base64 binary as the permanent format.

As for the other question...

**What is the best way to include images in an HTML email?**

This is an incredibly broad topic on its own and there are a great many blog posts on the alternatives for how to include images.

This is an article that SendGrid wrote on the subject:

https://sendgrid.com/blog/embedding-images-emails-facts/

As you can see there are multiple options each with pros and cons.  Which one is right for your use case is not something I can tell you.  My advice would be to research the alternatives and select the one that works best for your application and the email clients you wish to support.